# What would make a custom post type template not show up?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

So I am working on a WordPress-site and I needed to create a custom post type. I have the  function setup to initialize it with WordPress

```
add_action( 'init', 'init_staff' );

function init_staff(){
 register_post_type('staff_members',array(
   "labels" => array(
     "name" => "Staff Members",
     "singular_name" => "Staff Member",
     "menu_name" => "Staff Members",
     "add_new" => "Add New",
     "add_new_item" => "Add New Staff Member",
     "edit" => "Edit",
     "edit_item" => "Edit Staff Member",
     "new_item" => "New Staff Member",
     "view" => "View",
     "view_item" => "View Staff Member",
     "search_items" => "Search Staff Members",
     "not_found" => "No Staff Member Found",
     "not_found_in_trash" => "Staff Member Not Found in Trash" 
    ),
    "public" => true,
    "supports" => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    "has_archive" => true
 ));
```

}

I then created a file of single-staff_members.php with the WordPress loop in it and yet when ever I navigate to [www.mysite.com/staff_members](http://www.mysite.com/staff_members) or [www.mysite.com/staff_members/post_title](http://www.mysite.com/staff_members/post_title) I get the the page you are looking for doesn't exist 404.

Here's the single-staff_members.php file

```
<?php
   get_header();
?>
<div id="leftcolumn">
   <div class="main-content">
      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Sorry, no posts found.<p></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
</div>
<?php
   get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Reload custom links if You use them (go to prettylinks and save there). Thats first stem. If will not help, than replay.

Comment: Also if doesnt work, show how your single-staff_members.php looks like.

Comment: <?php
  get_header();
?>
<div id="leftcolumn">
   <div class="main-content">
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>Sorry, no posts found.<p></p>
 <?php endif; ?>

      </div>
   </div>
<?php
  get_footer();
?>

Comment: Paste in replay to Your question, or edit oryginal question ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by reload custom links, I tried deactivating and reactivating the plugin.

Comment: But from what I see... how this query should know what to display?
Proppably You should read about taxonomy.php file, and it would be better solution for You. You could also build a query with WP_Query() and parameters directing to get custom taxonomy posts.

Comment: No plugin. In backend, goto Options -> pretty links (permalinks), where You change, how link structure of Your site looks like (instead of standard links with post id at end) - save there without changing anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refresh permalink structure (Settings->permalinks click save).

Comment: I am super glad I saw your answer, this could have got me bad!

Comment: To do this automatically instead of by manually clicking Settings->permalinks in your wp-admin you can add `flush_rewrite_rules();` directly after you call `register_post_type( $key, $args );` in your custom post type creation. Happy coding!

Comment: OMG. If I had known this before, I would not have wasted too much time looking for the solution. Almost 3 days thinking what I did wrong with my CPT. (I did not have internet connection those days to find a solution). Thank you.